# How to use reverse proxy to get content of any url

Tags: php, apache, nginx, iframe, reverse-proxy

I want to create web application in Laravel PHP,so user will add any URL in my application then that URL will be open in iframe and all the content will be loaded in iframe, right now I have used curl to fetch data of URL,but some of sites are secure so I am not able to get data of those sites like `sendgrid`, it gives me error - **Refuse to connect**. I have done some research and concluded that to use reverse proxy so there will not be problem with CORS. But I don't know how to use proxy to get content of any URL. Please help me with that

my application is on Apache server and some one suggest to use nginx as reverse proxy server
so I have done setup of application apache port 8080 so my virtual host is `local.project.com:8080/` and URL for opening iframe is `http://local.project.com/openview-iframe/{encoded_id_of_url_data_storedIn_DB}` but unable to get content of site

my code is :

```
$url = base64_decode($url);
               
                $pUrl = parse_url($url);
                // ["scheme"]=>"http" ["host"]=>"geeksforgeeks.org" ["path"]=>"/php/" ["fragment"]=> "basics"
                $bUrl = $pUrl["scheme"].'://'.$pUrl["host"].'/';

                $ch = curl_init();
                $timeout = 5;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                
                // echo var_dump($data); die;

                $basehref = '<head> <base href="'.$bUrl.'/">';
                if (strpos($data, '<head>') !== false) {
                    $data = str_replace("<head>", $basehref, $data);
                }else{
                    $data = $basehref.$data;
                }
                echo $data;
```

Comment: If you're trying to avoid CORS or iframe restrictions you don't need a reverse proxy. All you need to do is make the request from a non-browser environment. That could be your existing PHP server.

Comment: But it's not clear if you have a CORS error or not, it sounds like you might be using PHP to fetch the data already. You've only given fairly vague details of the setup and the problem.

Comment: hey @ADyson  thanks for your quick response,  but  what do you mean by  existing PHP server and non-browser environment?

Comment: @ADyson I have updated my question and added code to get content please check that

Comment: Well a browser is a browser, so (in the context of what I said before) anything which makes a http request and isn't a browser is, by definition, a non-browser environment. A PHP program which makes a HTTP request would fall into that category. From your update it looks like you already have such a thing. Which makes me think maybe your problem isn't really about CORS at all, but as I said, the details are not very clear

Comment: okay what type of details you need to be clear ,  please tell me i will share that

Comment: If you're getting "refused to connect" as the result of your cURL request, then that can't be a CORS error, and it can't be related to iframes either. But it's not clear when/where you're getting that error - whether it comes from the curl request directly, or from something the page you're loading is trying to do after the content is placed in the browser, such as an Ajax request or something. Realistically, most sites do that these days, so trying to load a site into a separate environment like you're doing is unlikely to be very successful in most cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240378/discussion-between-santosh-dangare-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

Nginx can proxy the content, but be aware that proxied HTML content will probably not load sub-resources properly (CSS, JS, etc).

```
location ~ /url-proxy(.*) {
  proxy_pass https://$arg_host$1;
}
```

```
https://example.com/url-proxy/assets-stories-2021/css/index.min.css?host=about.google
  ⤷ https://about.google/assets-stories-2021/css/index.min.css

https://example.com/url-proxy/?host=about.google
  ⤷ https://about.google/
```